# Can socket.io listen/attach to a python http server?

Tags: python, node.js, socket.io

Sorry if I am not using the right terminology. I have a python HTTP server running on port 8000, which is basically equivalent to

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

If I try to create a socket connection on that same port using

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8000);
```

I get the following error

```
warn  - error raised: Error: listen EADDRINUSE
```

I understand that `listen(8000)` is trying to create an HTTP server on port 8000, but that port is already in use, hence the error.

So my question is: is it possible to create a socket connection on an existing HTTP server, which was started outside nodejs?  That is, could the "server" in this code

```
var server = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
```

be replaced by an already running HTTP server?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot have socket.io listen from a server created outside of the nodejs environment. Instead use Python websocket implementations such as https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio. It is the implementation of the socket.io protocol in python and is compatible with several notable python servers.

Otherwise, my recommendation will be just to have the 2 servers separately and don't combine them. That way, you have your main python webserver separate from your nodejs websocket server. You can create a separate socket.io server as such and bind it to a different port than your webserver:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8001);
```

On the frontend, then you need to connect to a different socket.io server as such:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://' + location.hostname + ':8001');
```